# Typeerror - Transaction must not include unrecognized value. Solidity/Python

Tags: python, solidity

I am taking a course in solidity/python, where I have encountered an error, which it does seem I can solve myself.

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc  # <- import the install_solc method!
import json
from web3 import Web3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

install_solc("0.6.0")  # <- Add this line and run it

with open("SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()


compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"simpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

# get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["simpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"]["bytecode"]["object"]

# get abi
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["simpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

#HTTP provider - connecting to ganache

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://XXXXXXX"))

#Network ID - Blockchain ID ganache
chain_id = XXXX

#Adress from ganache
my_address = "XXX"
private_key = os.getenv("my_private_key_1")
# From os env: my_private_key = os.getenv("Private_key_test_1")

# Create the contract in python 
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
#Get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)

# 1. Build a transaction
# 2. Sign a transaction
# 3. Send a transaction

transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {"gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
    "chainID": chain_id, 
    "from": my_address,
    "nonce": nonce}
)

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)

print(signed_txn)
```

I have the following error:

TypeError("Transaction must not include unrecognized fields: %r" % superfluous_keys)
TypeError: Transaction must not include unrecognized fields: {'chainID'}
PS C:\Users\VSCode-win32-x64-1.40.1\Project\demos\web3_py_simple_storage>

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

If you look on the readthedocs.io page for the function "buildTransaction" it shows that the named parameter in the transaction dictionary is "chainId" and not "chainID".  That's all.  Python is case-sensitive in that respect.  Good luck with your class.

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html

Comment: You're the man! Thanks a lot.